# Azure blob Container can still be accessed directly, even after being set to private

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have set a 'public' container where the blobs are stored as 'private', however irrespective of that I am still able to access the blobs directly with their URL within the container.

Any idea of why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: For questions like these, it really helps if you include a code snippet.

Comment: Hi David, when you go into your container, you will see there is a blob URL. The thing is you can access the private blob directly as long as you know the url.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But without showing code for how you set up permissions for container and blob, there's absolutely no chance of someone diagnosing this without a lucky guess.

Comment: @bobo2000, that information is not correct.  If the blob container is marked as private then you cannot access the blobs inside regardless of if you know the URL or not.

Comment: kwill was spot on, thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your browser or some other cache server is caching the file and you are not actually going to blob storage to get the file.  You can use Fiddler or Netmon to validate what requests are being made to storage, or perhaps try a different machine or an in-private browsing session.

Once a blob container is marked private you cannot access any blob in that container without the private key or a signed request.

Comment: Yep, it turns out my chrome was caching the file without realising.